# ERC1155 total Supply not showing?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging, erc-1155

I want to be able see the total supply of each token. I have imported the extension and followed the erc1155 documentation with regards to totalSupply, however when deploying on Remix and calling total supply it shows as 0 even after minting? I cannot figure out how to be able to show how many of each id has been minted?
Here is my contract code, thanks.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC1155, Ownable {
        uint256 public constant Poloy = 1;
        uint256 public constant Leafy = 2;

        mapping (uint256 => uint256) public tokenSupply;

    constructor()
        ERC1155("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/3bz4r7c6q3fjmt2uoicyibx2nhf7q6gtsdgze277wzlnadbvfme/{id}.json") {}

//make sure opensea can read the link
    function uri(uint256 _tokenId) override public pure returns (string memory){
        return string(
            abi.encodePacked(
            "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeid3bz4r7c6q3fjmt2uoicyibx2nhf7q6gtsdgze277wzlnadbvfme/",
            Strings.toString(_tokenId),
            ".json"
        )
        );
    } 

    // Minting - If you do not have any poloy the contract will let you buy one
        function mintPoloy() public{
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender,Poloy) == 0,"you already have a polo ");
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender,Leafy) == 0,"you already have a token cheaty cheater ");
        _mint(msg.sender, Poloy, 1, "0x000");
}

    // Minting - If you do not have any leafy the contract will let you buy one
        function mintLeafy() public {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender,Leafy) == 0,"you already have a leaf ");
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender,Poloy) == 0,"you already have a token cheaty cheater ");
        _mint(msg.sender, Leafy, 1, "0x000");
}


function totalSupply(uint256 id) public view returns (uint256) {
    return tokenSupply[id];
  }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `tokenSupply` was never incremented.
I did a few changes to your contract:

- I added an increment on each function
- Since your code was duplicated, I moved it all in a `private` function
- I reduced the number of `error` messages (it costs a lot). This will optimize the size of your code

Try to make sure that your error messages don't exceed 32 characters (32bytes) otherwise it will be stored on 64bytes.

```
function mintPoloy() public {
    require(_hasMinted(), "Already minted cheater!");
    tokenSupply[Poloy]++;
    _mint(msg.sender, Poloy, 1, "0x000");

}

function mintLeafy() public {
    require(_hasMinted(), "Already minted cheater!");
    tokenSupply[Leafy]++;
    _mint(msg.sender, Leafy, 1, "0x000");
    
}

function _hasMinted() private view returns (bool) {
    return
        ((balanceOf(msg.sender, Poloy) + balanceOf(msg.sender, Leafy)) > 0)
            ? false
            : true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked, and was incredibly helpful